# How can I find the k cheapest stopovers between two airports, for a given date or range of days?

Tags: air-travel

Let's say I'll be in some city x on May 5 and some other city z on May 12. I'd like to visit another city y on or around May 8 till around May 12, but I don't have any strong preference as to which city y it is.

How can I find the cheapest flight (and preferably the k cheapest flights) going through x-> y -> z, where y is chosen based on the price? In other words, how can I find the cheapest stopover  between two airports, for a given date or range of days?

---

I tried to use Kiwi.com as shown in the screenshot below, but with such a search there is no guarantee that the first "Africa" is the same as the second "Africa" (and in practice is typically isn't).

[image]

Comment: FYI, I tried to do this with Google Flights, but it doesn't work.  While you can search for "Africa" for a one-way or round-trip ticket, it won't let you do so for a multi-segment flight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

1. Go to [airwander.com](https://airwander.com/)
2. Click on the "Roundtrip" drop-down menu, and change it to "One Way"
3. In the origin and destination airport boxes type "Addis Ababa - ADD" and "Paris - CDG" (One limitation seems to be that you do need to select a specific airport rather than just "Paris")
4. Enter the departure date (5/8/20)
5. Click the red "+" button and let the website do it's thing for a few seconds.
6. The result is a list of stopover destinations sorted by the amount of money they would add to the non-stopover price (from low to high).
7. To change your desired stopover length, use the -/+ buttons near the upper right-hand corner of the page.
8. If you want to look into specific flights, click on that stopover destination, and click the blue search button.

Looks like the most inexpensive option for the example you gave is a stopover in Rome, but for $80 more you could stopover in Casablanca (that's the cheapest African stopover). Hope that helps!

[image]